# Is it impossible to code a function that just calls another one with zero overhead in C++?

Tags: c++

Suppose that there is a function with a pass-by-value parameter:

```cpp
void Test(Object obj){}
```

There are three possible ways for users to pass in the parameter:

```cpp
Object a;
Test(Object{});     // pass a prvalue; benefit from C++17 copy elision.
Test(a);            // pass a lvalue; trigger copy ctor.
Test(std::move(a)); // pass an xvalue; trigger move ctor.
```

But there seems to be no way to code a `TestWrapper` to behave in the same way. For example, `std::invoke` in the standard library has just the exact purpose:

```cpp
std::invoke(Test, Object{}); // pass a prvalue; nope, an additional move ctor.
std::invoke(Test, a);            // same.
std::invoke(Test, std::move(a)); // same.
```

That's essentially because perfect forwarding will bind the parameter to a reference so it has to be temporarily materialized. But if we pass by value, it'll be lvalue so the prvalue constructs the result object, even leading to a copy when passed again. Both ways fail to achieve the goal.

So is it impossible? If it is, are there any proposals that try to improve it, or it's just not cared about?

Comment: Not as long as function involves calling through a stackframe. But why pass a class by value anyway, pass by reference `void Test(const Object&)`  to avoid copies.

Comment: @PepijnKramer For example, a class with a data member `std::vector<std::string> vec` and a method `void AddValue(std::string str) { vec.push_back(std::move(str)); }`. This method may lead to an additional move ctor if an xvalue is passed, but it saves the trouble to code a template to perfect forward or write overloaded `const std::string&` and `std::string&&`.

Comment: You can't have zero overhead when there is one or more parameters to a function.  Passing the parameter, regardless of method, is considered overhead.  You should take a look at the generated assembly language for your function calls.  The truth is in the assembly language.  With zero parameters, the function call becomes a "jump" instruction or a "branch and return" instruction.  The minimal overhead is setting up the return location.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Right, but it may be eliminated, though in a non-standard way, by forcing inline like `__attribute__((always_inline)) inline` in gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given **separate translation**, it’s not in general possible to implement (compiling) such a wrapper: its caller would need to know where in the wrapper’s stack frame to construct the object, which depends on the implementation of the wrapper.  It’s also not possible to get the **destructor timing** right without significant changes to language semantics: if the caller destroys the (unique!) parameter, the real value would get destroyed too late in

```
void TestWrapper(Object o) {
  Test(std::move(o));  // or whatever more exotic syntax
  after_destroying_value();
  before_destroying_o_itself();
}
```

and if the callee destroys it, the moved-from value gets destroyed too early there.

Of course, if your special member functions are sufficiently simple, you can’t **observe** the moves/destructions, so implementations can and often do optimize away these operations, at least when inlining is possible.